# Change DrawingManager default cursor

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to change default DrawingManager mouse cursor? From default crosshair to custom.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible via the API, but currently the cursor will be set via the style-attribute of a div inside the map, so it's possible to select the particular div and override the style.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map div[style*='crosshair'] {
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA4e2.jpg?s=48&g=1")24 24, crosshair !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Works great - but only with certain image formats. Be sure you use PNG or JPG for example (SVG didn't work for me) and - the most important - the "image encoding"... I think it's the wrong technical term, but anyway, if you type in terminal "file your_cursor_image.png" then you get something "like your_cursor_image.png: PNG image data, 128 x 128, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced" -> 8bit colormap and non-interlaced is the thing to go.

Comment: as a note, IE 11 and Edge apparently don't support PNG / JPG files, so `.cur` files are your friend for cross-browser compatibility ...