# How do I change the cursor of the drawing manager for the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, drawing

I am setting up my drawing manager, like this:

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControl: false, 
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON],
        },

        polygonOptions: {
            strokeColor: "#FF00F0",
            fillColor: "#FF00F0",
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            editable: true,
        }
    });
```

And i start it with this:

```
drawingManager.setMap(_map);
```

But I get cross-hairs for the cursor and I would like to change it to a pencil. I can see from inspecting the web page that there is a div assigning the cursor but there is no way i can see to access it via the Maps API

```
<div style="z-index: 2000000000; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/crosshair.cur&quot;), crosshair; touch-action: none; position: absolute; left: -463px; top: -539px; width: 926.167px; height: 1078.03px;"></div>
```

Does anyone know How I could assign a different cursor when using the Google Maps API Drawing Manager?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change DrawingManager default cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492276/change-drawingmanager-default-cursor)